# How many solutions for $\frac{1}{a^4 + b^4} + 4(a + b) \ge \frac{5}{2} + 6\sqrt{ab}$?

Tags: inequality

Find more ideas for two variables inequality.

Let $a, b > 0$. Prove that
$$\frac{1}{a^4 + b^4} + 4(a + b) \ge \frac{5}{2} + 6\sqrt{ab}.$$
I found this problem on AOPS but I haven't accessed it recently. I want to find others ideas

I attach a proof by @dragonheart6.

We have
$$\frac{1}{a^4 + b^4}
\ge \frac{1}{a^4 + b^4 + (a - b)^4}
= \frac{1}{2(a^2 - ab + b^2)^2},$$
and
$$3(a + b) - 6\sqrt{ab}
= 3(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b})^2
= \frac{3(a - b)^2}{(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})^2} \ge \frac{3(a - b)^2}{2(a + b)}.$$

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{2(a^2 - ab + b^2)^2} + a + b
+ \frac{3(a - b)^2}{2(a + b)} \ge \frac{5}{2}$$
or
$$\frac{1}{(a^2 - ab + b^2)^2}
+ \frac{2(a^2 - ab + b^2)}{a + b} + 3\cdot\frac{a^2 + b^2}{a + b} \ge 5.$$
Using AM-GM, it suffices to prove that
$$5\sqrt[5]{\frac{1}{(a^2 - ab + b^2)^2}
 \cdot \frac{2(a^2 - ab + b^2)}{a + b} \cdot \left(\frac{a^2 + b^2}{a + b}\right)^3} \ge 5$$
or
$$2(a^2 + b^2)^3 - (a^2 - ab + b^2)(a + b)^4 \ge 0$$
or
$$(a^2 + ab + b^2)(a - b)^4 \ge 0.$$

We are done.

I hope we can find other proofs. Thank you for interest.

Comment: jokehim's proof is simpler: By AM-GM,
$\frac{1}{a^4+b^4}+4\sqrt[4]{\frac{(a^4+b^4)}{32}}\ge\frac{5}{2}$. The left is smooth.

Comment: @RiverLi Is that  your solution? I remember your AOPS is is dragonheart.

Comment: @TATAbox I mean described in my comment it is jokehim's proof.

Comment: @RiverLi Dragon boy attached your solution, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Remark.* Thank you @RiverLi's hint, here is a solution.

**Proof.**

We may use AM-GM as $$\frac{2}{a^4+b^4}+4\cdot\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4}{2}}\ge 5\implies \frac{1}{a^4+b^4}\ge \frac{5}{2}-2\cdot\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4}{2}} .$$
Thus, it remains to prove$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4}{2}}\le 2(a+b)-3\sqrt{ab},$$which is also true by AM-GM.

Indeed, it's
\begin{align*}
    &\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4}{2}}\\&=\sqrt[4]{\frac{\left(a^2+b^2+\sqrt{2}ab\right)\left(a^2+b^2-\sqrt{2}ab\right)}{2}}\\&=\sqrt[4]{\frac{\left(a+b+\sqrt{(2-\sqrt{2})ab}\right)\left(a+b-\sqrt{(2-\sqrt{2})ab}\right)\left(a+b+\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{2})ab}\right)\left(a+b-\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{2})ab}\right)}{2}}\\&=\sqrt[4]{\frac{a+b+\sqrt{(2-\sqrt{2})ab}}{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}\cdot\frac{a+b-\sqrt{(2-\sqrt{2})ab}}{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}\cdot\frac{a+b+\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{2})ab}}{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}\cdot\frac{a+b-\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{2})ab}}{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}\\& \le 2(a+b)-3\sqrt{ab}.
\end{align*}
Hence, the proof is done. Equality holds iff $a=b=1.$

Comment: It is quite complicated to follow.